Room Database IllegalArgument Exception
I'm building an application for tools, however
I'm getting this error when trying to build my project based on Room database
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: @androidx.room.Database does not define an element autoMigrations()
Here are relevant settings
build.gradle (Module:app)
compileSdk 34

def room_version = "2.6.1"
implementation libs.room.runtime
annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

versionCode 1
versionName "1.0"

I've looked everywhere, googled it, Stack Overflowed it, to no avail. PLEASE help
@Database(entities = {ToolList.class, Tools.class}, version = 1)

public abstract class RoomToolDatabase extends RoomDatabase
{
    public abstract ToolListDAO toolListDAO();
    public abstract ToolDAO toolDAO();
    private static volatile RoomToolDatabase INSTANCE;

    private static final int NUMBER_OF_THREADS = 4;
    static final ExecutorService databaseWriteExecutor =
            Executors.newFixedThreadPool( NUMBER_OF_THREADS );

    static RoomToolDatabase getDatabase( final Context context )
    {
        if( INSTANCE == null )
        {
            synchronized( RoomToolDatabase.class )
            {
                if( INSTANCE == null )
                {
                    INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder( context.getApplicationContext(),
                                    RoomToolDatabase.class, "tool_list.db")
                        .addCallback( callback )
                        .build();
                }
            }
        }

        return INSTANCE;
    }

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    private static final Callback callback = new Callback()
    {
        @Override
        public void onCreate( @NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db )
        {
            super.onCreate( db );

            databaseWriteExecutor.execute( () ->
            {
                // Populate the database in the background.
            } );
        }
    };
}


@androidx.room.Database does not define an element autoMigrations()
Have you tried .... defining such an element?

What is libs.room.runtime?

@Leviathan libs.room.runtime is part of build.gradle(:app) and is an implementation dependency, it is the NEW way of doing things, Sir Android, the annotationProcessor is annotationProcessor libs.room.compiler, I think it's to eliminate the need to worry about what the latest version is, and is being applied to most dependencies

It looks like it's coming from a version catalog. What I wanted to know: What artifact and what version is defined for libs.room.runtime? It's like a variable name, I want to know what's actually inside it.

@Leviathan All of the dependencies, as I've just discovered, go into a file called libs.versions.toml, in there I found all the depenencies and their related version Number. I'm assuming this gets automatically updated as required. I also sorted the [libraries] section alphabetically to make it easier to read with no issue. The version of room is 2.6.1.  NOTE, I have also fixed the problem see below.

ANSWER
Above in my reply to Leviathan I quoted the libs.versions.toml file, there is also under the Debug menu a submenu called Edit Libraries and Dependencies, by ensuring that all versions were the same in both of these, which they weren't, I have managed to sort the problem out.
libs.versions.toml can be edited and updated with correct versions as before in gradle, by hovering and accepting the request.
Edit Libraries and Dependencies automatically updates any other problems you have, by selecting each one and responding to the suggestion, if any.

The more important thing is to also move "androidx.room:room-compiler" to the version catalog and remove def room_version = "2.6.1" so you only have one location in your setup where the version is defined.

@Leviathan , yes thanks, was done
